# In a space where certain occupied areas are known, how can I see if a given area is unoccupied?

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a space ranging from 0-100 and along this space certain areas are occupied. Say 20-30 and 50-70.

Now let's say someone comes along and wants fill spaces 80-90. How would I best check if those spaces are unoccupied?

I could store the free space in nested arrays (which is what I'm currently doing):

`[[0, 19], [31, 49], [71, 100]`

and the loop an if statement checking if 80-90 will fit in any of these free spaces. This seems very inefficient. Worst case I could be talking thousands of items to loop through.

I could also use an array 100 items long with info on if each number is free:

`(100) 0: "free" 1: "free" 2: "free" 3: "free" 4: "free" ...`

This way I would not have to loop through multiple items but could just run the if statement on items 80-90 and see if they return free. On the other hand this would mean populating and storing an array with billions (100 is just an example, my use case involves around 1 billion)of items just to find free space.

How would one go about doing this in a better way? Or should I be using these methods I described?

Edit: I am using 0-100 as an example. In my use case, the number is actually around 1 billion.

Comment: The numbers don't add up, if you have spaces from 0-100 then why would you need to loop through thousands of items, or need an array with millions of items?

Comment: @GuyIncognito, the example is only for 100 items, not for millions ...

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I should clarify that 100 was only an example to explain the situation. In reality the number will be around 1 billion.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, that's why "storing an array with millions of items" doesn't make sense. How many spaces are there really? Reducing the amount for the example isn't necessary and is in fact harmful because the solution for 100 spaces is very different from the solution for a billion spaces.

Comment: @GuyIncognito My apologies... I have attempted to edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take an array of free ranges and perform a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

This would result in a max iteration of 20 by having a million of items.

```
2 ** 20 === 1048576
```

Comment: Thanks, I am somewhat new to this and hadn't been able to think of anymore complex solutions than the ones given. Binary search seems like a good way to go. I'll have to look into implementing it.